# AngularJS, PHP and json_decode

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to send values from AngularJS to PHP like below

loginService.js

```
'use strict';

app.factory('loginService',function($http)
{
   return{
       login:function(user){
                var promise = $http.post('data/user.php',user); //send data to user.php
                promise.then(function(msg){
                    if(msg.data=='succes') console.log('succes login');
                    else console.log('error login');   
                })
       }
   }
});
```

My PHP file is like below

user.php

```
<?php
    $user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

    if($user->mail=='foysal@gmail.com' && $user->pass=='1234')
    {   
        print 'succes';
    }
    else 
    {   
        print 'error';
    }
 ?>
```

My output is like below

```
error login
```

loginCtrl.js

```
'use strict';

app.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,loginService)
{
    $scope.login=function()
    {
    loginService.login();
    }
})
```

Could anyone say where is my mistake??

Thanks

I am getting a message like this "**`<br />↵<b>Notice</b>: Trying to get property of non-object in <b>D:\php\htdocs\login_angularjs\app\data\user.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />↵"`**"

How can I debug here ?? Like, is php file getting values ?? is php file sending values ??

**UPDATE**

I think I failed to gather the values
from the HTML Form. I am giving HTML Form code here.Could you help me
to figure out the issue ??

login.tpl.html

```
Welcome : {{user.mail}}

<div class="bs-example">
    <form role="form" name="form1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Welcome : {{user.mail}}</p>
            <label for="exampleInputEmail">Mail</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name"
class="form-control" required ng-model="user.mail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password"
id="exampleInputPassword" class="form-control" required
ng-model="user.pass">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"
ng-disabled="form1.$invalid" ng-click="login(user)">Submit</button>
        <p></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't show how you use loginService. Also, it is bad idea to communicate this way. Use JSON responses. `json_encode(...)`. in PHP

Comment: please learn to using proper spacing when posting code...

Comment: @SharikovVladislav thanks for your reply. How can I use json_encode() here ?? Thaks

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this in PHP:

Helper:

```
function getReturnObject ($message, $code) {
    $response = new StdClass();
    $response->message = $message;
    $response->code = $code;
    return $response;
}
```

Main code:

```
print json_encode(getReturnObject('auth is successull', 200);
```

Or:

```
header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
print json_encode(getReturnObject('auth is bad', 403);
```

Then in JavaScript you need this:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);
module.controller('myCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
  var user = null; // some user
  $http.post('data/user.php', user)
    .success(function (data) {
    // handle response there
    })
    .error(function (data) {
      console.log('error');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sharikov Vladislav for your reply. I used `$user=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`. Should I use `$user=json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` ??  
How can I debug PHP file ??
Thanks

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) post